# Inserting a new node into XML with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have an XML schema that I'm trying to insert new nodes into:

```
<clusters>
  <cluster>
    <name>
      cfcluster
    </name>
    <port>
      45564
    </port>
    <sessionreplication>
      true
    </sessionreplication>
    <server>
      cfusion1
    </server>
    <server>
      cfusion2
    </server>
    <stickysession>
      true
    </stickysession>
  </cluster>
</clusters>
```

I'm trying to write a script that has a new sever value, will check it against existing ones, then insert the new one after existing ones if it isn't found.  Say for example I have a new server value cfusion3, I'd want my new output to end up like this:

```
<clusters>
  <cluster>
    <name>
      cfcluster
    </name>
    <port>
      45564
    </port>
    <sessionreplication>
      true
    </sessionreplication>
    <server>
      cfusion1
    </server>
    <server>
      cfusion2
    </server>
    <server>
      cfusion3
    </server>
    <stickysession>
      true
    </stickysession>
  </cluster>
</clusters>
```

Assuming I have the xml stored in $clusterData and the new server I want to insert is stored in $cfInstance.name, I was thinking I'd use something like this, but can't get it working...

```
if (-not ($clusterData.clusters.cluster.server -match $cfInstance.name)) {
    $oldServer = ($clusterData | Select-Xml '/clusters/cluster/server').get_node()
    $newServer = $clusterData.CreateElement("server")
    $newServer.InnerText = $cfInstance.name
    $clusterData.InsertAfter($newServer, $oldServer)
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that `$oldServer` is getting all `<server>` nodes and I'm not sure how to modify the `xpath` to get just one.  I've tried:
 `Select-Xml -Xml $clusterData -XPath "clusters/cluster/server[text()='cfusion2']"`

 but that doesn't return anything.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XPath to return *only the last* existing `server` element :

```
/clusters/cluster/server[last()]
```

`/clusters/cluster/server[text()='cfusion2']` didn't work possibly because the inner text of the corresponding `server` element isn't exactly equals to `"cfusion2"`. There are white-spaces that you didn't consider. Try using `normalize-space()` to clean up unnecessary white-spaces before doing comparison, like so :

```
/clusters/cluster/server[normalize-space()='cfusion2']
```

Comment: har07's answer fixed the xpath issue, either of those are getting the correct element now for $oldServer. Unfortunately now when I try the InsertAfter() method I get the following error: Exception calling "InsertAfter" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node." At line:1 char:1 + $clusterData.InsertAfter($newServer, $oldServer) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: @RichHopkins call `InsertAfter()` on the parent element you want to insert the node, something like : `$clusterData.clusters.cluster.InsertAfter($newServer, $oldServer)`

Comment: Weird, when I piped $clusterData.clusters.cluster to Get-Member earlier I thought I didn't see that method being available, but that did the trick, thanks!