# Powershell - XML Insert a new line in an existing section

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an unpacked default install of an XML file that comes pre-populated with XML settings, like this...

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="false" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
</system.web>
```

I have a set of environmental changes to make on every release, so it adds one additional line to the system.web section...

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="false" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

This is to be used in an Octopus deployment, which I believe uses Powershell 2.0 as its base.

In Powershell scripts, how can I just add the...
   customErrors mode="Off" /
...statement to the existing system.web section of that XML file?

Thanks in advance
(prior linked duplicate question was not a concise answer - thanks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a new node into XML with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377080/inserting-a-new-node-into-xml-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, found it...

My XML before...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <anothernode>
     <notalot target="1" debug="dish" />
  </anothernode>
  <system.web>
     <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="false" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The Powershell code, I have chosen to use $var values instead, but nothing stopping you putting hardcoded things in the code, remember the '' quotes around them though!

```
# This will add <customErrors mode="Off" /> to the system.web section
$filename = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Neil\newxmlsettings.xml"
$var1 = 'customErrors'
$var2 = 'mode'
$var3 = 'Off'
#
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename
$body = [xml]$xml
$newnode = $body.CreateElement($var1)
$newnode.SetAttribute($var2,$var3)
$body.SelectSingleNode("//system.web").AppendChild($newnode)
$xml.Save($filename)
```

The "system.web" in quotes in the AppendChild statement is only required because it had a . in it, for single element names you can omit the double quotes around it.

Final XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <anothernode>
     <notalot target="1" debug="dish" />
  </anothernode>
  <system.web>
     <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="false" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
     <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do not read XML like that (`Get-Content` + `[xml]` type cast). This is wrong. Correct is `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load($filename)`.

Comment: Explanation: `Get-Content` will have no idea what encoding the XML file is in. When *don't* you specify an `-Encoding` parameter, it will take whatever is the default on your machine, resulting in mangled data when the file is actually encoded differently. When *do* you specify an `-Encoding` parameter, you still must know the XML file's encoding up-front to get it right (and you limit yourself to one encoding). When you use `XmlDocument.Load()`, the XML parser will figure out the file encoding transparently and it will work properly under all circumstances. So that is the correct choice.

Comment: @Tomalak my method works fine for this. You have highlighted a fundamental flaw in Powershell there though, in that it is an utter mess of 13 different ways to do the one-thing.

Comment: Not really. There are a million ways to do a thing in the wrong way. I have highlighted the correct way of loading an XML document, and this is entirely independent of Powershell. Loading XML as if it were text is *always* wrong. In any environment, in any programming language. "It works on my machine" is a weak defense.

Comment: @Tomalak Have you ever used the phrase "It works on my machine is a weak defence" in a real life face-to-face scenario? Try it and see if it works out for you. I would suggest that instead of telling me, aim high and tell the Scripting Guy over at Microsoft he is doing it all wrong, rather than dealing with small-fry like myself https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/tag/xml/

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You did something wrong and I am telling you, with a full explanation of what you did wrong and why. That's why you are here. If you can't handle criticism, that's your problem, not mine. Check your attitude. "It works for me" has always been the weakest reason to keep doing something wrong. And I am pretty sure the Microsoft Scripting Guy would a) not make this mistake and b) if he did, gladly accept a hint that it's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: "I have no idea what you are talking about" - I guess not. "Check your attitude" - brilliant - Enjoy your weekend @Tomalak

Comment: Do you have any actual arguments as well? I'd be very interested. Otherwise, don't come asking questions on a Q&A site if you don't like getting feedback. You have not managed to reply anything substantial so far, maybe you try that for a change.

Comment: @tomalak I'll come back if I feel like it, don't tell me what to do. "You have not managed to reply anything substantial so far" - really? The code above (where I answered my own question) works fine. Your method works fine as well, probably, and good for you. Your attitude and approach is what I object to. There are certain ways and means get your point across, but these are skills that don't match your coding ability.